# JTable Column resize isn't working

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

```
table.getTableHeader().setResizingAllowed(false);
column = table.getColumn(columns[0]);
column.setWidth(25);
column = table.getColumn(columns[1]);
column.setWidth(225);
column = table.getColumn(columns[2]);
column.setWidth(50);
table.doLayout()
```

This refuses to set the columns to their specified widths.  Any reason why?

Answer (score 3):

Swing ignores column widths set by you when resize mode of the `JTable` is not `AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`.
Instead of using `setWidth`, use `setPreferredWidth`. The table will then use this value when the columns are laid out. If you set minimum, maximum and preferred width, it should work for all occasions, but your users cannot change column width themselves anymore. So use this with caution.

The layout process is described in great detail in the [API-Docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#doLayout())

Answer (score 0):

To get this working for my table I overrode `setBounds` and set the preferred widths in there:

```
@Override
public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);

    setPreferredColumnWidths(new double[] { 0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.1 });
}
```

I got the implementation of setPreferredColumnWidths from this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/jdev/howtos/1013/jtablewidth/columwidth.html).

```
protected void setPreferredColumnWidths(double[] percentages)
{
    Dimension tableDim = getPreferredSize();

    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        total += percentages[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < getColumnModel().getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        TableColumn column = getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        column.setPreferredWidth(
             (int)(tableDim.width * (percentages[i] / total)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this working for ages, then I finally found that I needed to set `autoCreateColumnsFromModel` to false.

edit: ignore this, it was a consequence of firing tableStructureChanged when i wanted tableDataChanged (see discussion below, and thanks to kleopatra for identifying the mistake)

Comment: autocreate or not, the internal "layout" of column width is the same

Comment: kleopatra: i'm still learning my way around swing, so i can't really understand why it wasn't working, but if i comment out that one line the columns go back to being equally sized. code here if you want to take a look (clojure, but straightforward): https://github.com/martindemello/xw-clj/blob/master/src/clj/xw/swing/cluesheet.clj

Comment: that's because you are firing a structureChanged instead of a dataChanged. Anyway, there is something wrong with your setup somewhere: client code should _never-ever_ fire any notifications on behalf of a model: that's the inherent responsibility of the model itself

Comment: thanks! i'd misread the docs and thought i needed structureChanged when either the row or the column count changed.

Comment: as for why i need to fire the notification, my TableModel has getValueAt(row, col) pull the values from a dynamically scoped vector. i can't see how the model would know that some other code had changed the vector without my manually firing the notification.

Comment: implementing the model in such a way is simply invalid. Instead, let the model do the pulling and firing as appropriate. But that's it for here - if you have a question, post one :-)